# Listeners in and control flow in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, listener

How does a called function let the calling function know that he's done with all it's processing?

```
myFunction1(){

    myFunction2();

}

myFunction2(DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler callback){

    // Calls a web service and updates local files

}

myFunction2Returned(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e){


}
```

Start the whole call like this:

```
myFunction1();

// Continue processing here...
```

Now what I want to know is, if I call `myFunction1()`, how can you wait untill everything in `myFunction2()` has finished before you carry on with your processing? (that being whatever lies beyond the 'continue processing here...' comment).

The problem is that after I call `myFuntion1()` my code after that tries to read files that rely on `myFunction2()` to have completed it's web service call and completely written the needed files to disk.

I hope all this makes sense, was pretty difficult getting the wording right for the question to make sense.

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't it already work like this for you?

Comment: @J. Steen - Have a look at my edited question. A bit more detailed.

Comment: If the two functions run on the same thread it should wait

Answer (score 2):

You need to use async and await. You can write a function like this:

```
private async void SomeFunction()
{
    // Do something
    await SomeOtherFunction();
    // Do something else
}
```

As is in your case, this is especially useful for things like web service access where you don't have control over the processing of the other function. The keywords here are `async` and `await` which signal that the function is going to involve asynchronous programming.

Note that this syntax is relatively new (C#5), but since you didn't tag any specific version of .NET in your question I figured I would give you the latest and greatest ;).

Comment: `async` and `await` are just sugar, you should know what is going on into them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some tasks techniques for this, [something like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx):

```
static void SimpleNestedTask()
{
    var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // myFunction1 code here;
        Console.WriteLine("Outer task executing.");

        var child = Task.Factory.StartNew((t) =>
        {
            // myFunction2 code here
            // Calls a web service and updates local files
            Console.WriteLine("Nested task completing.");
        }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
   });

    parent.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Outer has completed.");
}
```